# How to add border around image without destroying layout?

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

Site: [is here](http://www.automatydrzwiowe.pl/trunk/index.php?module=guest&class=welcome&event=product&parent_id=31&menu_id=2)

picture html:

```
<img alt="" src="UserFiles/Image/galerie/12970854473D-Eco-60.jpg">
```

when I add `border: 2px solid black;` to the image

layout  breaks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only straight-forward solution to your problem that I can see is

```
outline: 2px solid black
```

which is layout neutral. However, it [doesn't work in IE < 8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Answer (score 3):

For the record, an alternative:

```
border: 2px solid black;
margin:-2px;
```

First you add 2px to all sides, and then you pull them back in with the negative margin.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS Clip, and apply the border around the clipped image;

I tried using margin: -2px, but it did not work for me.

Warning, CSS clip is pretty counter intuitive, and while it shares the a similar shorthand for margin and padding, it's pixel value assignments are extremely different compared to margin or padding.

Here are some helpful links;

1. Covers outline, and negative margin fix
   http://css-tricks.com/2368-image-rollover-borders-that-do-not-change-layout/
2. CSS Clip
   http://www.seifi.org/css/creating-thumbnails-using-the-css-clip-property.html